# Enum Array as parameter c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, enums

I am new to c++ and I want to include an array of Enum values, and I am getting a syntax error in Microsoft Visual Studio. I am not sure why this is the case any help much appreciated. The error number is C2061 and it states "syntax error: identifier 'VerboseBinary'. Here is the code:

Header file verbose_binary.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include <bitset>
    enum class VerboseBinary : int {
        One,
        Two,
        Four,
        Eight,
        Sixteen,
        Null,
    };

    void convert(std::bitset<5> bs, VerboseBinary aVB[6]);
```

verbose_binary.cpp

```
        #include "verbose_binary.h"
        #include "stdafx.h"
        #include <bitset>
        #include <string>
        #include <iostream>


        void convert(std::bitset<5> bs, VerboseBinary aVB[6]) {
            VerboseBinary VBArray[6] = {
                VerboseBinary:: One,
                VerboseBinary:: Two,
                VerboseBinary:: Four,
                VerboseBinary:: Eight,
                VerboseBinary:: Sixteen,
                VerboseBinary:: Null
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (bs.test(i)) {
                    aVB[i] = VBArray[i];
                }
                else {
                    aVB[i] = VerboseBinary::Null;
                }

            }
            aVB[5] = VerboseBinary::Null;

        }
```

Main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

#include "verbose_binary.h"

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::bitset<5> aBs, bBs;
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers between 0-31:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    if (a<0 || a>31) return -1;
    if (b<0 || b>31) return -2;
    aBs = static_cast<std::bitset<5>>(a);
    bBs = static_cast<std::bitset<5>>(b);
    // std::cout << aBs << " " << bBs << std::endl;
    VerboseBinary aVB[6];
    VerboseBinary bVB[6];
    convert(aBs, aVB);
    convert(bBs, bVB);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A downvote given with no reason why when I am a beginner is not very encouraging.

Comment: Please, read carefully http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You code is not minimal. You did not write line number of code with error. (I did not downvote you)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  `enum` with `class` became available with VS 2012.  Also, there is a stray comma at the end of your enum's definition. Also, stdafx.h should appear before any other includes in verbose_binary.cpp.  Main has a benign double-inclusion for `<iostream>`.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles thank you so much! Please post this as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: After removing all the Microsoft-ese gobbledygook (namely the `stdafx.h` silliness), the shown code compiles without errors with gcc 6.1.1. Either the error is in the code that's not shown, or this is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, so it looks like one of these issues was resposible for the error:

- What version of Visual Studio are you using? enum with class became available with VS 2012.
- Also, there is a stray comma at the end of your enum's definition.
- Also, stdafx.h should appear before any other includes in verbose_binary.cpp.
- Main has a benign double-inclusion for `<iostream>`